# Transfer contacts and data from non-smart device to a smartphone

Tags: contacts, mobile-data, data-transfer, nokia

How can I copy data (contacts in particular and then media maybe) from an ordinary phone to a new smartphone?
The old one is Nokia 105 (the dinosaurs one), a new one is Meizu c9
i know the difference is insane but that's for my gran, so..

Comment: Usually the stores that belong to an Mobile network Operator offer a migration service for phone contacts, sometimes free or for a cheap price. I would check this out.

Comment: What type of media are you talking about? Does the older phone not has a memory card where this media is stored, or does it not support storing/moving media into the memory card?

Comment: There are multiple versions of Nokia 105 available. The oldest I found is from [2015](https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_105_dual_sim_(2015)-7272.php) does that match the phone? Feature phone, no card slot, no Bluetooth, no USB data connection. Then the only possible way left is the SIM card address book.